# Can I automatically do Rolling, Blue-Green and Canary Deployments on Cloud Run (GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, blue-green-deployment, canary-deployment, rolling-deployment

I come from **AWS**. I used to automatically do **Rolling**, **Blue-Green** and **Canary Deployments** with **CodeDeploy** on **AWS**. Then, when I came to **GCP** and read [**Rollbacks, gradual rollouts, and traffic migration**](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/rollouts-rollbacks-traffic-migration), it seems like I can kind of manually do **Rolling**, **Blue-Green and Canary Deployments** on **Cloud Run** but not automatically.

So, are there any ways to automatically do **Rolling**, **Blue-Green and Canary Deployments** on **Cloud Run**?

Comment: There is nothing automatic and managed for now. However, you can try [that solution](https://medium.com/google-cloud/deploy-to-cloud-run-from-cloud-deploy-4f83628cf045) but I personally dislike it.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but there is a service called [Cloud Run Release Manager](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-run-release-manager) which seems to what you want.